# Page not redirecting after correct username and password

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```html
<body>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('LoginController/checkLogin'); ?>

Username:
<input type="text" name="username" /> </br> </br>
Password :
<input type="text" name="password" /> </br> </br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
```

```html
class LoginController extends CI_Controller
{
 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('login');
 }
 public function checkLogin()
 {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|callback_verifyUser');
  
  if($this->form_validation->run()== false)
  {
   $this->load->view('login');
  }
  else
  {
   redirect('HomeController/index');
   //$this->load->view('home');
   
  }
 }
 public function verifyUser()
 {
  $user=$this->input->post['username'];
  $pass=$this->input->post['password'];
  
  $this->load->model('LoginModel');
  if($this-> LoginModel ->login($user, $pass)){
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','Incorrect user........');
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

After correct username and password page is not redirecting to home page. What i am doing wrong please help me. Your Help would be appreciated.

Comment: use this `redirect(base_url() . 'HomeController');`

Comment: still giving me incorrect user... output.

Comment: What happens? Did you make sure that not any data has been sent to the client before (which would imply that a 201 status header has been already sent)? Do you use output buffering?

Comment: **upload your form code**. cant get idea from the conteroller

Comment: no i am nt using output buffering

Comment: `verifyUser()` and `checkLogin()` should be merge

Comment: can u suggest me how to i merge them?

Answer (score 0):

Load

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Change `redirect('HomeController/index');` to `redirect(base_url() . 'HomeController');`

> **Note :** If you redirect to controller `index()` function will called by default

**EDIT 01**

```
public function checkLogin()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|callback_verifyUser');

    if($this->form_validation->run()== false)
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else
    {
        $user= $_POST['username'];
        $pass= $_POST['password'];

        $this->load->model('LoginModel');
        $result = $this->LoginModel->login($user, $pass);
        if($result==1)
        {
            //call your page
            //redirect(base_url() . 'HomeController');
        }
        else
        {
            //$this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser','Incorrect user........');
            $this->load->view('login');//form view
        }

    }

}
```

In Model

```
public function login($user, $pass)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *FROM members WHERE user='$user' AND pass='$pass'");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result);
    if($count==1)
    {
        $log = 1;
        return $log;
    }
    else
    {
        $log = 0;
        return $log;
    }
}
```

Comment: in which file i do this $this->load->helper('url');

Comment: in `__constructor() `

Comment: still not working .is there any example to refer this

Comment: will check some tutorials to you

Comment: check [Php CodeIgniter Server Side Form Validation Example](https://arjunphp.com/php-codeigniter-server-side-form-validation-example/)

Comment: ok. there is no error but still redirecting to same login page when give correct input

Comment: @manisha can you **post your model**. i can solve your problem

Comment: all works now. add my **Model** code and **Controller** code